# Find UNC path for a DFS folder target

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to read files from a folder which is hosted within a DFS namespace. `DirectoryInfo` is unable to handle it, claiming the path doesn't exist, so I find myself needing to resolve to conventional UNC paths. This I can do to a certain extent: I can take the first part i.e. `\\domain\data` and map it to `\\fileserver1\share` by calling `NetDfsGetInfo()` from `netapi32.dll` as seen in questions elsewhere on SO.

The problem is, that's not enough. Within my DFS path is another folder, which isn't a real folder, it is I believe a folder with a folder target, which points to a directory not in the root of the target share. So while the folder path in DFS is `\\domain\data\documents` it resolves to `\\fileserver1\share\data\documents`.

Is there a way I can determine this programatically? If I pass `\\domain\data\documents` to `NetDfsGetInfo()` all I get back is `\\fileserver1\share`, and I haven't yet found anything that lets me examine that folder and figure out where that goes.

If only `DirectoryInfo` could just handle all this transparently for me like Windows Explorer does.